# How to do 2SLS IV regression using statsmodels python?

Tags: python, regression, statsmodels

I'm trying to do 2 stage least squares regression in python using the `statsmodels` library:

```
from statsmodels.sandbox.regression.gmm import IV2SLS
                 
resultIV = IV2SLS(dietdummy['Log Income'],
                  dietdummy.drop(['Log Income', 'Diabetes']),
                  dietdummy.drop(['Log Income', 'Reads Nutri')
```

`Reads Nutri` is my endogenous variable my instrument is `Diabetes` and my dependent variable is `Log Income`.

Did I do this right? It is much different than the way I would do it on Stata.

Also, when I do `resultIV.summary()`, I get a `TypeError` (something to do with the F statistic being nonetype). How can I resolve this?

Comment: Is the model meant to know that because ReadsNutri isnt in the instruments it is the endogenous variable? When I do as you have done for statsmodels I get weird results

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found this question when I wanted to do an IV2SLS regression myself and had the same problem. So, just for everybody else who landed here.

The [documentation of statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.sandbox.regression.gmm.IV2SLS.html) shows how to use this command. Your arguments are `endog`, `exog`, and `instrument`in that order where `exog` includes variables which are instrumented and `instrument` the instruments and other control variables. In that sense, your model is fine.

The `TypeError` you found is currently an [open bug](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/3544) in versions 0.6.0 and 0.8.1. and will be fixed in 0.9.0 according to the milestone.

**Update (28.06.2018)**: Version 9.0.0 was released on 15 May and should include a fix for the aforementioned bug.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I found [the IV2SLS function in linearmodels 4.5](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.sandbox.regression.gmm.IV2SLS.html) to be more intuitive than the statsmodels version, as it has separate parameters for the dependent variable and the endogenous variable(s), whereas the statsmodels version doesn't. The results I got from the linearmodels function lined up with what I would get with an Excel add-in I got through school.

If you choose to use the linearmodels function, [this guide](https://bashtage.github.io/linearmodels/doc/iv/examples/advanced-examples.html) should also help. For instance, it showed me that I needed to add in a constant for my function to produce the correct output.

Comment: I guess the link should be https://bashtage.github.io/linearmodels/iv/iv/linearmodels.iv.model.IV2SLS.html#linearmodels.iv.model.IV2SLS, no? Since you're talking about linearmodels