# How do I print results table for statsmodel 2sls

Tags: python, statsmodels

I'm using statsmodel's 2SLS similar like this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37012110/how-to-do-2sls-iv-regression-using-statsmodels-python)

However, I can't seem to figure out how to print the results.

print(results.summary()) results in: "'IV2SLS' object has no attribute 'summary'"

The [documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.sandbox.regression.gmm.IV2SLS.html) doesn't seem to have any info

Comment: I do not have the answer to your question, but if you are in a hurry, you can use the [linearmodels](https://bashtage.github.io/linearmodels/iv/examples/basic-examples.html) package that provides a summary representation when using the `from linearmodels.iv import IV2SLS` class.

Comment: @AdrienPacifico that isn't the direct answer to my question, but it ultimately got me the solution I needed. Thank you very much!